# RxJava Observable.create returns null when there is a value being passed to .onNext

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, google-calendar-api

I am fetching a calendar Event via ID from the google calendar V3 Java API, which is a wrapper of:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22eventId%22%3A%226msto66us6ou1ri503lem4absk%22%7D

When I call for the event, I wrap it in an Observable and pass it to a service that maps it, this service is then called via activities.

A problem I'm having is when I spin up the new Observable and call for the Event, the Event gets returned but then gets passed to Observable.next as null, which causes my application to blow up. When I debug, I can see the calendar event so I feel that it is some weird async/threading issue.

Here is the call for the event:

```kotlin
@Module
class GoogleCalendarsApiServiceModule @Inject constructor(): IGoogleCalendarsApiServiceModule {

    private lateinit var googleCalendarService: Calendar

    private val httpTransport: NetHttpTransport = NetHttpTransport()
    private val subscriptions: Disposable = Disposable.empty()

    init {
        this.subscriptions.apply {
            AndroidContextObservable.context()
                .subscribe { context ->
                    val googleCredential = GoogleCredentialsBuilder.getCredentials(httpTransport, context)
                    googleCalendarService = ServiceBuilder.buildGoogleCalendarService(googleCredential, httpTransport)
                }
        }
    }

    fun finalize() {
        this.subscriptions.dispose()
    }

    override fun getEventById(eventId: String): Observable<Event> {

        return Observable.create { observer ->
            val calendarEvents: Calendar.Events? = googleCalendarService.events()
            val event = calendarEvents!!
                .get("primary", eventId)
                .execute()

            observer.onNext(event)
            observer.onComplete()
        }
    }
}
```

Then the calling service which maps the event:

```kotlin
    override fun getCalendarEventById(eventId: String): Observable<FullMeetingEvent> {
        return this.googleCalendarsApiServiceModule.getEventById(eventId)
            .map { mapMeetingEvent(it) } // <-- skipped due to event being null/empty runnable
            .onErrorReturn { throw Exception(it) }
    }
```

and then finally the calling Activity:

```kotlin
class ViewMeetingEventDataActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var bundleUtilityModule: BundleUtilityModule
    @Inject lateinit var fragmentUtilityModule: FragmentUtilityModule
    @Inject lateinit var googleCalendarService: GoogleCalendarService

    private val subscriptions: Disposable = Disposable.empty()
    private lateinit var eventId: String
    private lateinit var event: FullMeetingEvent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        AndroidContextObservable.setContext(this)
        DaggerServiceModuleComponent.create().inject(this)
        DaggerUtilityModuleComponent.create().inject(this)

        this.eventId = intent.getStringExtra(BundleData.MEETING_EVENT_ID.name)!!

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_view_meeting_event_activity)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        subscriptions.apply {
            googleCalendarService.getCalendarEventById(eventId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(
                    {
                        event = it
                        setViewMeetingEventFragment(it)
                    },
                    {err -> println(err)}
                )
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        this.subscriptions.dispose()
    }

    private fun setViewMeetingEventFragment(meetingEvent: FullMeetingEvent) {
        fragmentUtilityModule.createSingleFragment<FullMeetingEvent, ViewMeetingEventDataFragment>(meetingEvent, BundleData.FULL_MEETING_EVENT.name, supportFragmentManager, R.id.view_meeting_event_data_container)
    }
}
```

Obviously as the service fails, the subscription in the activity goes straight to the error block.

I know I have the event, as digging around in the debugger, I managed to find it:

[image]

But as you can see in the code above the debugger, it is clearly creating a null observable.

It's like the observable has fired before the call for the event has finished but I have code that grabs all my events in the exact same way and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the service was swallowing the error and pushing s**t back up to the Activity. The actual error was coming from the mapper and trying to use something that was null. The fix is:

```kotlin
    fun mapMeetingEvent(googleCalendarEvent: Event): FullMeetingEvent {
        val attendees = mutableListOf<String>()
        var organiser: String;

        if(googleCalendarEvent.attendees != null && googleCalendarEvent.attendees.size > 0) {
            googleCalendarEvent.attendees.forEach { x ->
                if(x.displayName != null) {
                    attendees.add(x.displayName)
                }
                else {
                    attendees.add(x.email)
                }
            }
        }

        if (googleCalendarEvent.organizer.displayName != null) {
            organiser = googleCalendarEvent.organizer.displayName
        } else {
            organiser = "No organiser"
        }

        return FullMeetingEvent(
            googleCalendarEvent.description,
            googleCalendarEvent.summary,
            googleCalendarEvent.id,
            googleCalendarEvent.start.dateTime,
            googleCalendarEvent.end.dateTime,
            googleCalendarEvent.location,
            attendees,
            organiser
        )
    }
```

It's a shame that null checking has to be done like this but I guess it's how it be.